# cant add muteHttpExceptions without getting a syntax error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to enable the muteHttpExceptions option when executing a fetch, and for some reason im getting a syntax error that doesnt make any sense to me.

```
function test()
{
 LogData('113096243739111424')
}
function LogData(argProf)
{
var APIKey = "<Redacted>";
var IDLEURL = 'https://public-api.travitia.xyz/idle/';
var options =
{
  "method" : "get",
  "headers": {"Authorization": APIKey},
  "muteHttpExceptions":true
};
   var result = JSON.parse( UrlFetchApp.fetch(IDLEURL + '/profile?_select=*&user=' +argProf , options).getContentText());
  Logger.log(result);
};
```

This gives me an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token: < (line 17, file "adventure calculator")`

When i do:

```
var options =
{
  "method" : "get",
  "headers": {"Authorization": APIKey},
  //"muteHttpExceptions":true
};
```

i get the error `Request failed for https://public-api.travitia.xyz returned code 525. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html> <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 17, file "adventure calculator")`

i dont understand what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: In your script, the last character of `IDLEURL` is `/`. `'/profile?_select=*&user=' +argProf` is added to it. By this, the endpoint becomes `https://public-api.travitia.xyz/idle//profile?_select=*&user=113096243739111424`. In this case, you can see `idle//profile`. Although I'm not sure about the specification of the API you want to use, I think that this might be the reason of your issue. So for example, how about modifying `IDLEURL` to `var IDLEURL = 'https://public-api.travitia.xyz/idle';`? If this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: oddly enough, it actually just started working, a guy i am working on this with looked up error 525, and it looks like an SSL error. even with the extra `/`. i'll still fix it, but wierd that it works. EDIT: looks like the API server was down, and that was causing the 525. i feel dumb now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that if other error occurs even when this modification was done, it is required to confirm the specification of the API you want to use. So when the server is restarted, please test and check it.

Comment: Sorry i didnt reply sooner, It looks like it was ignoring some of the syntax issues when the API server was up, and not trying to do the muteHttpExceptions. when i tried to do muteHttpExceptions it would start catching the syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If an error occurs even if my 1st comment was reflected to your script, unfortunately, from the current information you provided, I cannot replicate and understand about your situation, because I cannot test it. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Dont worry about it. in the end you helped out.